# XSS Vectors for new Image()

Tags: xss, javascript

What are possible XSS vectors to this JavaScript code

```
new Image().src = encodeURI('[user url here]');
```

Let's assume two cases:

- `[user url here]` is some string provided by user (with no validation)
- `[user url here]` is a valid url (validated by Django [URLValidator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L68))

I'd imagine there are a lot of vectors for first case, ex.

```
javascript:alert('XSS')
```

But what about the second case? Are there any known vectors?

**UPDATE:**
The only vector I can think of is MIME sniffing attack

Comment: What about `http://localhost/'%2balert(1)%2b'`?

Comment: If our payload is not URL encoded, then this payload will cause XSS '-alert(1)-' but if its url encoded as the EncodeURI function is used. This wont work.